# magento cybersource payment method error "Credit card type is not allowed for this payment method"

Tags: magento, payment-gateway

i have magento community edition 1.9.0.1 and i have installed cybersource payment method extension in magento. While placing an order on front end i am getting the Below error:

"Credit card type is not allowed for this payment method."

```
  Credit card type is not allowed for this payment method.

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cybersource/Model/Soap.php(182): Mage::throwException('Credit card typ...')
#1 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Payment.php(160): Mage_Cybersource_Model_Soap->validate()
#2 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(631): Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment->importData(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/local/Apptha/Onestepcheckout/controllers/IndexController.php(493): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->savePayment(Array)
#4 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Apptha_Onestepcheckout_IndexController->saveOrderAction()
#5 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveOrder')
#6 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /var/www/html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /var/www/html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/dev/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Need help in this issue.

Comment: Pls print $this->getConfigData('cctypes') and let us know what is the result?

Comment: Visa, Mastercard are allowed types from backend of cybersource payment extension.

Answer (score 0):

Please log into your merchant account and set the cards types you want to accept.

Go to 
Payment Configuration -> secure acceptance settings -> edit your profile where you update card types.